# Xiangqi symbols in Unicode

Tags: xiangqi

Since [**Chess** symbols are part of Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode), I would like to know if **Xiangqi** symbols would be too.

If they are, where can we find them?
If they are not, is there a way to find some... in Unicode for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since XiangQi symbols are Chinese characters and Chinese characters are part of Unicode, you can certainly identify and use these characters to specify XiangQi symbols.

For example by copying the characters from the [XiangQi wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiangqi#Pieces) into this [translation tool.](http://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/converter-unicode.html)

Comment: Thanks, @BlindKungFuMaster. That's true, but I would expect a set of chars with the design of the Xiangqi pieces... And if I remember, I saw them in the past, inside a special character listing.

Comment: The design of Xiangqi pieces consists of the Chinese characters. And the Chinese characters are actually used to notate moves, for example in the wiki article I linked. Do you mean an additional circle around the char?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It would be awesome, if it exists.

Comment: Apparently there was a proposal to make Xiangqi symbols part of unicode in 2010, but I can't find out whether it actually happened: http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2010/10368-n3910.pdf

Comment: You could also try to find out whether you can combine Chinese characters with an enclosing circle, like in this question: http://superuser.com/questions/312966/using-the-combining-enclosing-circle-character-in-word

Answer (score 6):

Xiangqi symbols are now in Unicode 11.0, in the block [Chess Symbols: U+1FA00–U+1FA6F](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1FA00.pdf).